# How to make a Tableview or another view move up while maintaining constraints to to the bottomlayout?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, cgaffinetransform

I want to have my tableview increase in size and moves up when scrolled down while also keeping the constraint to the bottom layout. I thought I would try CGAffineTransform.

```
func MoveUP() {
        // pop up login screen
    let bottom = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -30)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {
            // Add the transformation in this block
            // self.container is your view that you want to animate
        self.numberOfProperties.transform = bottom
        self.tableview.transform = bottom


        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

The problem with this is that it moves up the tableview but does not keep the proper constraints to the bottom. Many apps seems to have this behavior, what tool am I missing in order to achieve this result?

Comment: How do you set the height, is it based on a constraint or set programatically? You should just change the property used to calculate the height.

Comment: I don't want to set a height for the tableview as It will change on different iPhone screens. Its set on constraints.

Comment: So you are using Autolayout? You must have a constraint for either the height or the top of the tableview. Just connect an outlet to that constraint and change it in code.